# Scala make List of strings from char array

Tags: scala

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
val StringSpace = charList.reduce(_ + _ + _ + _ + " ")
val StringList = //Tokenize StringSpace with " "
```

but it returns missing parameter type within first line.

So how can someone actually join lists into half or quarter size in scala?

e.g: From

```
List ("a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f" , "g" , "h")
```

To:

```
List("abcd", "efgh")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val l = List ("a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f" , "g" , "h")
l.grouped(4).map(_.mkString)
```

Comment: So how to make something like: List("abcd", "efgh") from "abcdefgh"?

Comment: Same thing. `"abcdefgh".grouped(4).toList`. A string behaves like a list of characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
charList.grouped(4).map(_.mkString).toList
```